# Add elements to View from subclass XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a problem with my first project in xcode. I add new class Lesson1 with main View and subview "Level1" is it possible add elements(programatically) to subview(highlighted) from class lesson1?. For example I wanna add UIButton to subview(highlighted) from Lesson.m. I added screenshots

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Lesson1]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, but rather include the code itself!

Comment: Also, what have you tried? What is your **specific** problem?

Comment: My problem is that I dont know how can I add new element to subview from lesson1.h. Sorry but I am novice in xcode.

Comment: You cant add just an element from one class to another. You can add the entire class though

Comment: Yes I can but I dont wanna because I will have about 30 levels and I should have 30 classess

Comment: But why would you want to add a button from Lesson 1? You can create a button in Level1 itself..

Comment: One element cannot have 2 view hierarchy structures.. If im not wrong this is what you are trying to achieve..